# Web Scraping using BeautifulSoup, click on element for hidden tab

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have an issue while I'm trying to capture specific information inside of the page.

Website: https://www.target.com/p/prairie-farms-vitamin-d-milk-1gal/-/A-47103206#lnk=sametab

On this page, there are hidden tabs named 'Label info', 'Shipping & Returns', 'Q&A' next to 'Details' tab under 'About this items' that I want to **scrape**.

I found that I need to click on these elements before doing **scraping** using Beautifulsoup.

Here is my code, let's say I've got pid for each link.

```
    url = 'https://www.target.com' + str(pid)
    
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    
    button = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': "TabHeader__StyledLI-sc-25s16a-0 jMvtGI"})
    
    index = button.index('tab-ShippingReturns')
    print('The index of ShippingReturns is:', index)
    
    if search(button, 'tab-ShippingReturns'):
       button_shipping_returns = button[index].find_element_by_id("tab-ShippingReturns")
       button_shipping_returns.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

My code returns
ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Can anyone kindly guide me how to resolve this?

Comment: It's *scrape* not *scrap*.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
button = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': "TabHeader__StyledLI-sc-25s16a-0 jMvtGI"})
```

will return a BeautifulSoup list of tags.

You then try to call a selenium method on that list with:

```
button_shipping_returns = button[index].find_element_by_id("tab-ShippingReturns")
```

Instead you need to call it on the webdriver element collection

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.TabHeader__StyledLI-sc-25s16a-0 jMvtGI')[index].find_element_by_id("tab-ShippingReturns")
```

Comment: Thanks, QHarr I found it has still an error message but I figured this out with the code from Vova below. Thanks for you help and support indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like buttons what you're trying interact have dynamically generated class by adding unique values at the end, I would suggest using contains() method of xpath selector types like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'TabHeader__Styled')]")
```

so, your code should looks like that:

```
   elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'TabHeader__Styled')]")
   for el in elements:
       el.click()
```

it's not horrible to click on the button where page already in

if element is not visible and need to scroll down, you can use ActionChains:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
```

so code looks like that, just your element parser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.target.com/p/prairie-farms-vitamin-d-milk-1gal/-/A-47103206#lnk=sametab'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'TabHeader__Styled')]")
for el in elements:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
    el.click()

driver.quit()
```